What process launches Microsoft Teams at login?
How does Microsoft Teams start at login?  In other words, what process launches Teams?
Enabling or disabling Teams at Startup via any method (Teams Settings, Windows Settings, and Task Manager) only changes the value State in the registry key below.
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TeamsStartupTask

Source: Re-enable Microsoft Teams on startup
I searched the registry (Run folders), startup folders, scheduled tasks, and used the Sysinternals utility Autoruns. If the application which launches Teams is there, then I missed it.
There must be a startup program which reads that registry value and decides whether or not to start ms-teams.exe.
What is it and how does it launch?

Autoruns shows pretty-much everything. You might not find the item by a name that taps you on the shoulder and say's, "Here is the mechanism that starts Teams." You'd need to do research, or experiment by turning Team autorun on and off and noting the diff.

As Teams is somewhat integrated into the OS, there may be other processes that handle this behavior, processes that are not exposed in the various known Startup locations.

Also, this question is very theoretical. What is the problem you are trying to solve that you believe learning Teams' startup mechanism is the solution to? Perhaps stepping back to that will give us a more practical question we can actually help you with.

@music2myear I am trying to block the actual mechanism and launch it later based on another condition on the server. It is not theoretical. Something exact launches Teams

So your question is not "what starts Teams?" but is instead "how do I stop Teams from starting except in X circumstances". While those may sound like the same question, they are not. I recommend that you edit your post to focus on what you are actually asking.

Have you checke via Task manager -> Startup app, select MS Teams, then click Properties?
